# Modify WebHost configuration after building it, to add the content of newly added files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to add fields to the IConfiguration I've given to my WebHost during its execution, not just on start up.

I have some files, each giving me the connection parameters for a distinct database. At startup, I load those files into the configuration builder to be able to use those information to connect to the database specified by the request sent to the service.

But I want to be able to react if I'm given new files during runtime. As such, I've set up a FileSystemWatcher to watch over the folder where those new files might appears. I tried to read the new files and add the key/value pair to the config, but it doesn't seems to register the change outside of the local context :

```
IConfiguration _config;

[...]

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in readFile)
{
    _config[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(_config[entry.Key]);
}
```

This does change the content of _config in the local context (the `Console.WriteLine(_config[entry.Key])` shows the correct result). But if I try to read it from outside the function (in the API controller for example) that treats the "new file detected" event, I only get an empty string.

Comment: Take a look examples in documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#custom-configuration-provider

However I'm not sure that it allows to update configuration dynamically. Since provider has build method. 

Apparently intent of configuration is start parameter for application.

Comment: You can take a look as an example or solution:
FileConfigurationProvider
https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/tree/master/src/Configuration/Config.FileExtensions/src

Or this one:
https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/tree/master/src/Configuration/Config.KeyPerFile/src